# Rotating clickable elements in IE8+

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8

I am attempting to rotate clickable elements in IE8 using the proprietary MS filter `DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix`. I've calculated the matrix correctly and the element is visibly rotated, however the area that responds to the click appears to maintain the same shape and position as before the rotation.

Example code which displays this problem:

Content of HTML:

```
<html>    
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"/>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="rotated">
            Element which is longer than it is wide...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Content of CSS:

```
.rotated {
    height: 15px; /* required for IE7 to perform rotation */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0, M12=-1, M21=1, M22=0, sizingMethod='auto expand');
}
```

Content of JS:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.rotated').click(function() {
        alert('You clicked within the original boundary');
    });
});
```

Clicking on the top left corner of the text will show the alert, however, anywhere on the visible text lower than the specified height will not register. Note that this does not perform the same in IE7; the clickable area is also rotated.

I have also tried using `progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);` in place of the matrix filter, however this has the same results.

Has anyone had to deal with this in the past, or have any information which would be helpful in this case?

**EDIT:** I've replicated this on jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/e46jD/

**EDIT:** Turns out I've been burnt for relying on IE9 to provide accurate emulation of IE8. Testing the code in an actual installation of IE8 works fine. So, now the only problem is with IE9 itself.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change a bit your markup, wrapping your text inside an extra `<span>` element, in this way

```
<div class="rotated">
    <span>Element which is longer than it is wide...</span>
</div>
```

then I accordingly changed the style (note, I've also changed `height: auto`, because some letters were cut)

```
.rotated { 
    border: 1px red solid;
    height: auto; /* required for IE7 to perform rotation */ 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(
            M11=0, M12=-1, M21=1, M22=0, sizingMethod='auto expand'); 
}

span { display: block; }
```

and javascript, so the click event is attached on `span`

```
jQuery(function($) { 
    $('.rotated span').click(function() { 
        alert('You clicked within the original boundary'); 
    }); 
});
```

In IE8 you can click also on the bottom area not covered by characters.

See the fork: http://jsfiddle.net/wdbK8/

Comment: As explained in my edit, that works for IE8. Any insight into making this work for IE9?

Comment: @metafunk I haven't IE9 for testing right now: what's wrong with it? It doesn't rotate text or it is not clickable?

Comment: What happens is that the element is visibly rotated, but the effective bounding box of the original element isn't rotated, so the only clickable part is the overlap of the two (effectively the top corner). I suspect it's something to do with only partial support for DXImageTransform.Microsoft.* filters, given that IE9 now supports -ms-transform CSS rules. I've given in and used browser specific classes for the elements :(

Comment: on IE9 you can use CSS3 2D transforms (http://caniuse.com/transforms2d) so basically use filter only for IE<8 and transform for IE9+. Remember to also change `(-ms-)transform-origin: 0 0;` otherwise rotation will be centered

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved the effective result in all browsers I was targetting by splitting the CSS rules up by browser support, and applying classes using conditional comments to deal with IE.

The big showstopper was the fact that IE9 would rotate the element visibly as a result of `DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0, M12=-1, M21=1, M22=0, sizingMethod='auto expand')` but wouldn't rotate the interactable bounding box. I've read since posting this question that IE9 has reduced support for filters, and so I've set it up so that for IE7/8 it uses the filter, and for IE9 it uses `-ms-transform`.

Less elegant, but now it works.

Comment: The Filter Transform is different from the -ms-transform (and other similar modern CSS transforms) anyway.  The rotation may be the same but the top offset is different.  If I recall my past research into it correctly, the filter adds to the top an offset so that any rotation of the element still has the same "top" as it would have were it not rotated (whereas with the CSS transforms, the object is basically rotated about the object's center, so it may overlap things before it).  Since you might have to account for said offset with the filter, what you've done here is what I'd propose.

Answer (score 0):

this solved my problem across all browsers. My text was getting clipped after rotation, the position, top and padding properties helped me out. width of 100% is important. filter and ms transform is imp for IE

```
#rotationCSS    { 
    width:100%;
    font-size:1.3em;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:right;  
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);  /* Chrome, Safari 3.1+ */
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);  /* Firefox 3.5-15 */
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg)!important;  /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);  /* Opera 10.50-12.00 */
    transform: rotate(90deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    padding: 35px 20px 0px 10px;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
}
```