# Clickable area rotated hyperlinks in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, css, rotation, css-transforms

When rotating hyperlinks in Internet Explorer 9, the painting to the screen seems to be handled fine, but the clickable area doesn’t appear to respect this.

Whether the rotation is done with `-ms-transform`, `filter`, or `-ms-filter` doesn’t seem to matter. It also doesn’t seem to matter whether you rotate the hyperlink itself (`a:link`), or its container (for example a `div`). With the latter, `overflow:hidden` isn’t respected either (again, for the clickable area; the painted area is clipped as expected).

Is there any way to fix this, or should I fall back to `area[coords]` (which, of course, is not preferable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly i'm having the same issue when trying to turn a button for 90 degrees. The clickable area in IE is only on the top of the button. Shitty IE =[

I really don't want to use an image for a button...

Found out this thread: [Rotating clickable elements in IE8+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876322/rotating-clickable-elements-in-ie8) maybe it will help you (and me)...

Comment: Seems like that thread does not offer a solution for IE9 either. (I would be surprised if it did, since my code already used the proprietary `DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix`.) One solution (read: workaround) I came up with is using `area`’s with `type="poly"` and `coords` values corresponding to the coordinates of the area that should be clickable (and putting them in IE conditional comments). However, I did not use this for the project because it did not help the hover effects I also needed.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this solution ([Rotating the button using CSS3 and applying it on absolute right position doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930610/rotating-the-button-using-css3-and-applying-it-on-absolute-right-position-doesn))

Copying text here for reference:

> I've fixed it by using -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); Somehow that wasn't added in the generator i've used online. Clickable area works now in IE. – user1466179

Comment: I had a background image for a rotated button that was not showing up in IE9 with the above fix. Here is what I did:
I used both 

    `filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2);`
    `-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);`

to rotate 270 deg (108+90) and the clickable area worked fine, and also my background image showed up. I now did not have to change 'right' css for IE, it works with the same that I used for Chrome and firefox!