# Rotating the button using CSS3 and applying it on absolute right position doesn't work

Tags: css, rotation, position, absolute

Im trying to rotate a button (with) CSS3 styles (gradient) by 90degress and apply it on absolute right:0px position. That button is "About us".

It seems like there are 2 problems. First is that the button element doesn't go all the way to the right (like I want it) and it seems that the problem is in CSS3 rotation that still thinks 150px width. If I disable the rotation, the element is aligned to the right screen perfectly, with no space left out.

Also I found that in Google Chrome, when i hover over the button "Kaj točno delam", it doesn't apply gradient correctly - meaning there is 1px (or 2) of black space on the button before the gradients starts (from left to right) - this however doesn't happen, when being in normal (horizontal) mode, or is being turned to the right (when i tested). It's also strange because that doesn't show as big when using Chrome Developer tools to toogle element :hover.

Using Internet Explorer the vertical button "About us" only works when pressing it on top (and nowhere else).

Do all of this problems happen because of CSS3/HTML bug?

Is there any better solution to do this without using images? - perhaps using jQuery or something else?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you rotate an element, the width stays the same. You need to calculate your right-position like this:

```
-(width/2-height/2) = -(150/2-27/2) = -61,5
```

So you need to take `right: -61,5px;`  in stead of `right: 0;`

Comment: I did that, but i don't think that IE support right:-61,5px, because when i tried it, IE showed it like it's now (right:0px).

Also i still don't know if CSS3 is the right way to do it, since you can't press the button in IE except if you press it on the top - the whole buttons isn't clickable.

But thank you for your effort and suggestion =).

Comment: If you really want IE support, you better use images instead of 2d transforms.

Comment: I've fixed it by using -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); Somehow that wasn't added in the generator i've used online. Clickable area works now in IE.